# CMD multiple entries to copy to a txt file

Tags: windows, cmd

I was wondering if it was possible to copy more than just one output from CMD to a text file.
I need this for work, i have a script made in Autohotkeys, and there's roughly 8 commands, and i need the all to be automaticly placed in a text file.

I tried the mycommand > txt.txt, but that overwrites the last written thing in the txt.
I know one solution, I'm using CLCL, so i have up to 30 clipboards, so I could use this with the | clip option, but that's more work than just copying the cmd.

Any help is appreciated.

Patrick.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo first line>test.txt
echo second line>>test.txt
echo third line>>test.txt
type test.txt
```

`>` means "write to", create / overwrite if already existent

`>>` means "append to", append / create if not already existent